# How to access files in a non-shared folder of a pc over LAN?

Tags: windows, lan, file-transfer

Say I have 2 Windows 8 PCs connected over WiFi in a home network. Is it possible to silently access / explore files and folders of one PC using the other using any app /windows feature?

Comment: if you have admin on the remote box, check to see if the admin shares are available (c$, d$, IPC$, etc).

Comment: So as Frank suggested above, you need to know the administrator password on the machine you will access remotely and it has to be enabled. You'll need the PC name or the IP address assigned to that machine as well.  The syntax you'd use would be from RUN `\\<IPAddress>\c$` or `\\<PCName>\c$` and then press ENTER, it'll try to connect via SMB so that traffic needs to be allowed through the Windows Firewall as well. Then you'll put in the username and password to gain access to the hidden admin shares i.e. `c$`, `d$`, etc. where the letter before the dollar sign represents the drive letter...

Comment: See this article as well... http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows-8.1-administrative-shares,2-749.html   I think enabled printer and file sharing used to allow these connections with older versions of Windows so that's something to check as well if you do not get prompted for username and password on Windows 8, I don't have anything to test this with right now at home.